# Rails.logger, info and puts doesn't work for my Ruby on Rails application running on Amazon Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-linux

Our Ruby on Rails project is running in Amazon Linux EC2 instance, we use `Rails.logger` to save the log.

The logging file was always generated under `\var\app\containerfiles\logs`, I was also able to use the `info` command or `puts` command to log the event. But recently, the logging file is not generated any more.
The code for initialize Rails logger is as below:

```
    Rails.logger = Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'server.log'))
```

The ruby version was 2.6, I upgraded it to 2.7, but it doesn't work either.

Could yo uplease give some hints why this happens?

Comment: I hope you restarted the server after the changes.

Comment: Thanks, I restart server, but doesn't work.

Comment: Sometimes in AWS environments, I have seen the rails logs redirecting to the puma logs ( in /var/log/puma/)  Worth a try!